# Difference between number in txt

Tags: php, minecraft

I'm currently busy creating 3D Rollercoaster rides in minecraft. I used a small NoLimits 2 plugin to get me some output data. and pre-proccessed it for php. Currently only need the x y z coordinates

Piece of the pre-proccessed file:

```
47.71394|1.5|-10.34523
47.73439|1.5|-10.34828
47.75566|1.5|-10.35144
47.77783|1.5|-10.35473
47.80088|1.5|-10.35815
47.81917|1.5|-10.36086
47.83271|1.5|-10.36286
47.84702|1.5|-10.36497
47.86219|1.5|-10.36721
47.87823|1.5|-10.36957
47.89509|1.5|-10.37205
47.91286|1.5|-10.37466
47.92018|1.5|-10.37574
47.92836|1.5|-10.37694
47.9374|1.5|-10.37826
47.94727|1.5|-10.37971
```

Although it doesnt differ here as much as on other places i need to convert this to relative difference for the Minecraft Plugin i use. PHP got me so far already.

i want to take the difference between every step and put that in a file like this

```
- 'run:move 0,0,0.1,0,0'
- 'wait:1'
- 'run:move 0,0,0.1,0,0'
- 'wait:1'
```

Or by using the first two data's

```
line 2:    47.73439|1.5|-10.34828 
line 1:    47.71394|1.5|-10.34523  -
          ---------------------------
output 1:     0.02045|0|-0.00305
```

And then the output just needs to convert to [Or even just be]

```
- 'run:move  0.02045,0,-0.00305,0,0'
```

Continue for the next 2 lines
    line 3:    47.75566|1.5|-10.35144
    line 2:    47.73439|1.5|-10.34828  -
              ---------------------------
    output 1:     0.02127|0|-0.00316

The last two of that move thing doesnt need to be changed, but how do i go on to get the differences in a for loop [Also need to be dynamic].
Some file will just be 800 lines long, others can be 1500+

Current php code for adding | to code and removing unnecesary No Limits 2 location data

```
<?php
//CustomRideMC 3d FROM NL2

$lines = file('CustomRide.txt');
$n = 0;
foreach($lines as $line) {
    $coords = explode(" ", $line);
    echo $coords[0]; // piece1
    echo "|";
    echo $coords[1]; // piece2
    echo "|";
    echo $coords[2]; // piece3
    echo "<br>";
    $n = $n + 1;
}
```

Comment: I kinda have a feeling we're missing some information here. `difference between every step` - What step? And how are you coming up with the data in the file you want to create? Because that doesn't seem to be relative to the pre-processed file at all?

Comment: A step is a new line
The format is X|Y|Z
and i need to get the difference from
1  X|Y|Z and 2 X|Y|Z (Creates the first X|Y|Z)
2  X|Y|Z and 3 X|Y|Z (Creates the second X|Y|Z)
And so on
- 'run:move 0,0,0.1,0,0'
is the movement on x,y,z axis  [The other 2 are pitch and yaw]
the wait bit, tells the Minecraft Plugin to wait 1 tick [1/20th of a second]
By knowing the relative difference i can imitate No Limits 2 movements in minecraft

Comment: you mean you want to check next line with php ?

Comment: How does `'run:move 0,0,0.1,0,0'` relate to your data? None of the lines you show have a difference of `0.1`. Please make your `run:move` match **exactly** what you are expecting out of the first couple lines of your data.

Comment: @Makyen
See now, added a better explanation [will do line 2 and 3 too!]

Comment: Ah, now it's making sense to me. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it. Explanation in comments:

```
<?php

/* Input TXT file */
$finput = 'inputfile.txt';

/* Array to hold all lines */
$lines = array();

/* Process 2 lines from array */
function processLines($line1, $line2){

    /* Output TXT file */
    $foutput = 'outputfile.txt';

    /* Explode lines to array */
    $line1 = explode('|', $line1);
    $line2 = explode('|', $line2);

    /* Substract and round to 5 digits behind the comma */
    $x = round((floatval($line2[0]) - floatval($line1[0])), 5);
    $y = round((floatval($line2[1]) - floatval($line1[1])), 5);
    $z = round((floatval($line2[2]) - floatval($line1[2])), 5);

    /* Get the lines we've already processed */
    $content = file_get_contents($foutput);

    /* Create new line and add it to content */
    $content .= "run:move ". $x .",". $y .",". $z .",0,0\r\n";

    /* Put content back in file */
    file_put_contents($foutput, $content);
}

/* Read through input file */
$handle = fopen($finput, "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        array_push($lines, $line);
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    echo 'Unable to open file';
    exit;
}

/* Loop through array by 2 steps*/
for($i = 0; $i < count($lines); $i+=2){
    processLines($lines[$i], $lines[($i+1)]);
}

?>
```

Output using your example data:

```
run:move 0.02045,0,-0.00305,0,0
run:move 0.02217,0,-0.00329,0,0
run:move 0.01829,0,-0.00271,0,0
run:move 0.01431,0,-0.00211,0,0
run:move 0.01604,0,-0.00236,0,0
run:move 0.01777,0,-0.00261,0,0
run:move 0.00818,0,-0.0012,0,0
run:move 0.00987,0,-0.00145,0,0
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, of course, but:

```
$A = $B = $C = 0;  // initialize the holders of the 'previous' point
$first = true;
foreach($lines as $line) 
{
    $coords = explode(" ", $line);
    if($first)
    {
        $A = $coords[0];
        $B = $coords[1];
        $C = $coords[2];
        $first=false;
        continue; // output nothing for the first point, move on
     }

     $a = $coords[0] - $A; // take difference between current point
     $b = $coords[1] - $B; // and previous one
     $c = $coords[2] - $C;

     echo "run:move  $a,$b,$c,0,0"; // Do you need a line feed here?
                                    // Might need to add "<br>" or "\n" 
                                    // to the end of the line, depending
                                    // on what reads the output
}
```

If you need to ensure that the inputs are floats, use this:

```
 $A = floatval($coords[0]); // etc for all 3
```

If you need to control the decimal precision of the output, add lines like this to render the numbers before outputting:

```
 $a = sprintf("%2.5f", $a); // 2.5 means two digits before the decimal
                            // point, and five digits after
```

Comment: I would avoid answering with untested code. An anwer is supposed to solve the question. If you're not sure your answer will solve it, it's not an answer. It's a comment. If someone tests your code and it doesn't work, you can expect downvotes coming in.